# Show the order at which buttons are clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to show the order at which buttons are clicked. For example I have the html

```
<button id="one" class="name">Hello</button>
<button id="two" class="name">Hello1</button>
<button id="three" class="name">Hello2</button>
<button id="four" class="name">Hello3</button>
<button id="five" class="name">Hello4</button>
```

If I click any button for the first time, for example let's say third one with id="three", then it should show "1" on top of button. If I click it again it should say 1&2 and then if I clicked another button then that button should say 3 as it is clicked at 3rd position.
So the whole thing is I am trying to show the position at which they are clicked and if they are clicked multiple times then show at which numbers they are clicked and join the numbers with "&".
PS: I am new to jquery/javascript so I am not able to figure out where to start to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code with pure Javascript. No additional library required. You can run and try it on the snippet below. The steps can be described here:

1. Set the counter variable and assign it to 0
2. Get all the buttons elements.
3. For each button, add the event listener and the mechanism of count text and the counter:

   - If the button had not been clicked yet, then add `clicked =`  and the current state of counter.
   - Otherwise, just add the ampersand `&` and the current counter state.

```js
var click = 0;
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button.name');
buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var current = button.innerText;
    var existingClicks = current.split(" ");
    if(existingClicks.length > 1) {
      button.innerText += ` & ${++click}`;
    }
    else {
      button.innerText = `clicked = ${++click}`;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<button id="one" class="name">Hello</button>
<button id="two" class="name">Hello1</button>
<button id="three" class="name">Hello2</button>
<button id="four" class="name">Hello3</button>
<button id="five" class="name">Hello4</button>
```

If you wish to add reset button, you can encapsulate it on a `div` and save the early state of it:

```js
function click(){
  var click = 0;
  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button.name');
  buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', function(){
      var current = button.innerText;
      var existingClicks = current.split(" ");
      if(existingClicks.length > 1) {
        button.innerText += ` & ${++click}`;
      }
      else {
        button.innerText = `clicked = ${++click}`;
      }
    });
  });
}

var container = document.querySelector('.container');
var reset = document.getElementById('reset');
reset.addEventListener('click', () => {
  container.innerHTML = `
  <button id="one" class="name">Hello</button>
  <button id="two" class="name">Hello1</button>
  <button id="three" class="name">Hello2</button>
  <button id="four" class="name">Hello3</button>
  <button id="five" class="name">Hello4</button>`;
  click();
});

click();
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.reset {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button id="one" class="name">Hello</button>
  <button id="two" class="name">Hello1</button>
  <button id="three" class="name">Hello2</button>
  <button id="four" class="name">Hello3</button>
  <button id="five" class="name">Hello4</button>
</div>
<button id="reset" class="reset">Reset</button>
```

Remember that you need to encapsulate the upper part into a function and run after you "re-initialize" the buttons actions in the container.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed instructions. I understood it now.

Comment: Hi @Ritik, would you mind giving this answer an upvote?

Comment: I gave it but it's saying I need at least 15 reputation to do that and I have 7 right now. Will definitely upvote after reaching minimum required reputation.

Comment: How to reset the buttons if I click reset button. For example - <button class="clear">Reset</button> should reset all the buttons to the original and I should be able to click them again like before?

Comment: @Ritik Done the edit, feel free to try and probably change the accepted answer as well if possible. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
 var click = 0;
$("button.name").click(function(){
  var current = $(this).text();
  var existingClicks = current.split(" ");
  if(existingClicks.length > 1) {
    $(this).text(current+" &"+(++click))
  }
  else {
    $(this).text("clicked = "+(++click))
  }
})
});
```

I think this code will do what you want to do without much editing in your HTML side. But I would suggest you to use better classnames for the elements.

Comment: It worked. I will change classnames accordingly.

Comment: One more question. How to limit the clicks. For example total of 3 clicks will output max number 3. When I will make 4th click on any button then it won't show number 4.

Comment: You see there is the "click" variable which contains the number of times buttons were clicked. You can add condition in your click handler like.

If (click > 4)
return false;

Comment: How to reset the buttons if I click reset button. For example - <button class="clear">Reset</button> should reset all the buttons to the original and I should be able to click them again like before?

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out why you want to separate numbers with '&' but its easy.

```js
var btn1Clicks = 0;
var btn2Clicks = 0;
var btn3Clicks = 0;

var btn1 = document.getElementById('one');
var btn2 = document.getElementById('two');
var btn3 = document.getElementById('three');

btn1.addEventListener('click',btnClick);
btn2.addEventListener('click',btnClick);
btn3.addEventListener('click',btnClick);

function btnClick(e){
  let btnclk = 0;
  if (e.target == btn1 || e.target.parentNode == btn1){
    btnclk = btn1Clicks + 1;
    btn1Clicks ++;
  }
  else if(e.target == btn2 || e.target.parentNode == btn2) {
    btnclk = btn2Clicks + 1;
    btn2Clicks ++;
  }
  else{
    btnclk = btn3Clicks + 1;
    btn3Clicks ++;
  }
    
  let s = e.target.getElementsByTagName('div')[0] || e.target;
  
  let str = s.innerText;
  if (str === '' && btnclk == 1){
    str = '1'
  }else{
    str += `&${btnclk}`;
  }
  
  s.innerText = str;
}
```

```css
.name{
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #1122a9;
  color: white;
  width: 160px;
  margin: 15px;
}

.txt{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<button id="one" class="name">Hello <div id="txt"></div></button>
<button id="two" class="name">Hello1 <div id="txt"></div></button>
<button id="three" class="name">Hello2 <div id="txt"></div></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var click = 0;
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button.name');
buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var current = button.innerText;
    var existingClicks = current.split(" ");
    if(existingClicks.length > 1) {
      button.innerText += ` & ${++click}`;
    }
    else {
      button.innerText = `clicked = ${++click}`;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<button id="one" class="name">Hello</button>
<button id="two" class="name">Hello1</button>
<button id="three" class="name">Hello2</button>
<button id="four" class="name">Hello3</button>
<button id="five" class="name">Hello4</button>
```